# I need to create SYNONYM with name 'END'

Tags: enterprisedb

Using EnterpriseDB I am not able to create/drop `SYNONYM` with name 'END'

```
DROP SYNONYM END;
CREATE SYNONYM END FOR TABLENAME;
```

I am getting similar issue while creating table with column name `REFERENCES`:

```
create tab1
( name character varying(250), 
REFERENCES character varying(250) )
```

I am converting the table from Oracle to Postgres (EntrepriseDB). In Oracle (`END`, `REFERENCES`) are used. Hence I need to use the same words here, too. Is there any way to use the reserved key words as synonyms name and column name?

Comment: I can see the code as a nightmare: `SELECT CASE "END" WHEN 'END' THEN NAME ELSE "END" END "END", ...`

Comment: with double quotes it is started working

Answer (score 3):

`END` and `REFERENCES` are both reserved keywords.

So if you really want to use them as names (of tables, columns, schemata, synonyms, ...  whatever), you have to double-quote them, the same way as in Oracle:

```
CREATE SYNONYM "END" ... ;
DROP SYNONYM "END" ;

CREATE tab1
( name character varying(250), 
  "REFERENCES" character varying(250)
) ;
```

The problem is that you have to always double-quote them everywhere and match the case. `"END"` is not the same as `"End"` nor `"end"` nor `"eNd"`, etc.

It would be much easier to use non-reserved words for all identifiers.